# How to edit metadata/ID3 of every filetype (.mp4, .mp3, .mpeg, .m4a, etc.) in C#?

Tags: c#, mp3, metadata, file-type, id3

I started to look for a method to change the metadata of each file in my music library. There are a lot of different filetypes like .mp4, .wma, .mp3, etc. The only thing I found was the [UltraID3Lib](http://home.fuse.net/honnert/UltraID3Lib/), which is only for .mp3 files.

Is there an option to change the metadata of every different filetype

Does anybody have any idea or experience in this kind of development?

Comment: For those who downvote: I provided every information asked for in "How to ask", and please leave a note if you really have to downvote! Without information I have no possibility to improove my question. And yes, I know that there is no question concerning my specific question!

Comment: You might want to look at the source for VLC Media player.  I believe it lets you view and edit the metadata on almost any file type.  Maybe GIMP as well. You may have trouble finding a single library that can do it all.

Comment: @MobyDisk VLC uses TagLib (http://taglib.github.io/). But in the documentation there is no way to access the API via C#, only via C++. But I have no experience at all in using C++. But thank you for your reply.

Comment: Good research.  Oh hey, a Google search turns up a Taglib# and even a nuget package for it.  That seems promising.

Comment: @MobyDisk You are absolutely right. There seems to be a Nugget-Package for it. I am installing it and I'll try to mess with it around :) Thank you for your help. If you provide it as an answer, I will accept it as the correct one.

Comment: This is really a 'find a library' for me question, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you found TagLib, try out TagLib# AKA (taglib-sharp).  There is even a nuget package for it.